# Set builder of this set $0$, $1$, $3$, $6$, $10$, $15$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have tried to create the set builder of this infinite set:

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28,...
```

I have notice that

$n = (n - 1) + (N + 1)$

where `n` is the current number, `n - 1` is the previous number and `N + 1` is a natural number which represents the number of numbers before `n`.

For example, suppose $n=3$

```
3 = 1 + 2
```

The problem is that I do not know how to really represent `N-1`, because, if we do not know how many numbers that are before `n`, we cannot find `N+1` and therefore `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that we start with $z = 0$, and that the zth element of the sequence $a_z$ is defined by $a_z = a_{z-1} + z$. This is basically the set of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

With an induction proof, we also can prove that the correct representation of the zth element is $a_z = \frac{z(z+1)}{2}$.

To express this as a set, I would denote it as $\{\frac{z(z+1)}{2}|z\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: @cell: added that

Comment: I'm busy at the moment and can't find notation that includes 0, but it shouldn't be too difficult to sort out

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's a sequence, not a set. secondly, this might work?: 
$$a_0=0, a_n=a_{n-1}+n$$

Which yields:
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$
So,  like @agha pointed out, as a set it is:
$$\{\frac{n^2 + n}{2} \space | \space n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \}$$

Comment: Yes of course. But notice that in order to build it, the "subscript" was used, i.e it's a function of "position" (a natural number)

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). The answer is:

$$\left\{{n+1\choose2} :\ n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you look at double the sequence, we see $0 \times 1, 1 \times 2, 2 \times 3,\ldots$